# Making Rails javascript code DRY

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dry, gon

I have two files that use some common javascript code and the rails gon gem.

So for file 1: `file1.js` looks like this

```
$(function () {

   function a() {
    ....
   }

   $('id').on('click', function() {
     c = gon.obj1
     c.doSomething
     ....          
   })

   function otherMethods(){
   }
})
```

For file 2: `file2.js.erb` I have,

```
var c = abc
function a() {
  ....
}

$('id').on('click', function() {
  c.doSomething
  ....          
})

//other code
```

Now I am considering making my code DRY by extracting the common code in `file3.js`:

```
function a() {
  ....
}

$('id').on('click', function() {
  c.doSomething
  ....          
})
```

Since I am new to javascript, I am not sure about how I could populate c such that both `file1.js` and `file2.js.erb` to work correctly.

1. How do I pass var c as an argument to the common file from file1 and file2, to the common code (let's call it `file3.js`)
2. Do I just do something like `<%= javascript_include_tag "file3.js" %>` in `file2`, and similarly in `file1` to access the common code?

Eventually I want to have `file1.js` to look like:

```
$(function () {

   function otherMethods(){
   }
})
```

and `file2.js.erb` to look like

```
//other code
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails uses sprockets to load javascript files from the primary `application.js` file. If you look at that file you'll notice how all the javascript files are loaded with `require_tree .`. You can copy this technique in your `file3.js` like so.

**file3.js**

```
//=require file1
//=require file2

// your code here...
```

In your first example the function `a()` won't be available globally without adding it to `window`.

**file1.js**

```
window.a = a;
```

Comment: but how do I send different values of c to file3 from file1 and file2? also check my updated question just so I can be more clear